# re.sub doesn't modify string in python

Tags: python

I have a small python program where I expect the word "verified" (regardless if written in upper, lower case or a mix of upper and lower case). To be reset to "Verified". How do I need to rewrite the code below?

```
 import re
 text="verified, vERIFIED, VERIFIED"
 text=re.sub(r'\verified', 'Verified', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
 print text

Expected output: Verified, Verified, Verified

Actual output:verified, vERIFIED, VERIFIED
```

Comment: remove the backslash before the `v` so `text=re.sub(r'verified', 'Verified', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you. This is the answer. However when the word started with ? then the backslash was needed. How come? e.g : text=re.sub(r'\?verified', 'Verified', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: `?` means the preceding group/character is optional so if there wasn't a backslash it would still work

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the backslash before the `v`

```
import re
text="verified, vERIFIED, VERIFIED"
text=re.sub(r'verified', 'Verified', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print text
```